# Unable to open your web browser to 'git@...' , do you have a default web browser set?

Tags: github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

[image]

On the icon bar of Atlassian SourceTree the Remote-globe icon shows a red exclamation point badge indicating an error.  When clicked, a pop up message appears saying "Unable to open your web browser to 'git@git-ssh... do you have a default web browser set?"

[image]

I do have a default web browser set (Firefox) but Atlassian is still unsatisfied.  All other features appear to be working fine, but the red exclamation badge is nagging at me. Security and access seem to be happy and all repository operations are working normally.  The message is specific to the currently open repository Tab and the url in the message is the same url shown in the Repository Setting for the origin of that repository, which is correct and working.

I suspect there is a setting that can be added to the Repository Settings Config file to fix this and don't believe it has anything to do with the "default browser".  It is more likely related to the "Remote Account" settings shown in the Advanced Repository Settings window.  Or possibly a conflict caused by the VPN or our corporate repository url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with the "default browser".  When you click on the Remote-Globe icon it should attempt to redirect you to a web-based browser of your repository that you must first define in the Repository Settings Optional extended integration window.

[image: Repository Settings Window]

To reach this window click the Repository pull-down Menu, Select Repository Settings.. and you will see the Repository Settings Popup menu.  From the Remotes Tab select the "origin" line that contains the path to the remote depository.  Then click on edit, and the "Remote Details" popup window should appear.

[image: Remote Details Window]

From the "Remote Details" popup window you can select the public Bitbucket, GitHub, Unknown, or Bitbucket-Server as your Host Type.  Select "Bitbucker-Server".  Then enter an HTTPS:// based URL to your company's bitbucket-server under "Legacy Account Settings".

Once this is done, you should be able to click on the Remote-Globe icon and start a browser view of the remote repository.  (It may be necessary to enter your host's username and password too.)